# TypeError Can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: pytorch, numpy-ndarray, tensor

i got this error message. I understand that numpy does not support GPU yet. How shall I modify the code to get away from this error without invoking tensor copy data operation, tensor.cpu() ?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 2, figsize=(15, 15))
modelname = ['DenseNet_0', 'DenseNet_1', 'GooglNet', 'ResNet101', 'VGG16 with BN']

i=0

for row in range(5):

  epoch_list = list(range(1,epochs*2+1))
  
  ax[row][0].plot(epoch_list, accuracies['train'][i:20+i], '-o', label='Train Accuracy')
  ax[row][0].plot(epoch_list, accuracies['val'][i:20+i], '-o', label='Validation Accuracy')
  ax[row][0].plot([epochs for x in range(20)],  np.linspace(min(accuracies['train'][i:20+i]).cpu(), max(accuracies['train'][i:20+i]).cpu(), 20), color='r', label='Unfreeze net')
  ax[row][0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, epochs*2+1, 5))
  ax[row][0].set_ylabel('Accuracy Value')
  ax[row][0].set_xlabel('Epoch')
  ax[row][0].set_title('Accuracy {}'.format(modelname[row]))
  ax[row][0].legend(loc="best")
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 6>()
8   epoch_list = list(range(1,epochs*2+1))
9
---> 10   ax[row][0].plot(epoch_list, accuracies['train'][i:20+i], '-o', label='Train Accuracy')
11   ax[row][0].plot(epoch_list, accuracies['val'][i:20+i], '-o', label='Validation Accuracy')
12   ax[row][0].plot([epochs for x in range(20)],  np.linspace(min(accuracies['train'][i:20+i]).cpu(), max(accuracies['train'][i:20+i]).cpu(), 20), color='r', label='Unfreeze net')

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in **array**(self, dtype)
968             return handle_torch_function(Tensor.**array**, (self,), self, dtype=dtype)
969         if dtype is None:
--> 970             return self.numpy()
971         else:
972             return self.numpy().astype(dtype, copy=False)

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

Comment: You cannot, you need to copy the data back to the CPU.